# How to plot a horizontal number line with ggplot, having 0 at the center?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use `ggplot2` to plot a horizontal number line with 0 at the center to compare different items along that axis.

### Example

Say that we're interested in the effect of diets given to different mice. Each mouse is fed with a different type of food, and after a month we compare the mice to each other in terms of weight. For each mouse we want to know whether there was a weight gain or weight loss, and by how much.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- 
  data.frame(mouse = c("Mickey", "Jerry", "Gonzales", "Remi"),
           weight_pre = c(10.1, 6.2, 9.5, 13.3),
           weight_post = c(9.2, 12.4, 2.3, 10)) 


df_with_diff <-
  df %>%
  mutate(diff = weight_post - weight_pre)


df_with_diff
#>      mouse weight_pre weight_post diff
#> 1   Mickey       10.1         9.2 -0.9
#> 2    Jerry        6.2        12.4  6.2
#> 3 Gonzales        9.5         2.3 -7.2
#> 4     Remi       13.3        10.0 -3.3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

### Desired Output

I'm trying to achieve a simple horizontal number line like the one below, with 0 at the center:
(clearly this is not drawn to scale, but just to demonstrate my intention)
[image: number_line]

Any idea how to do this (or something close enough) with `ggplot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `pointrange` and `theme_minimal`. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggrepel)

df_with_diff %>%
        mutate(min = ifelse(diff > 0, 0, diff),
               max = ifelse(diff > 0, diff, 0)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = diff, y = mouse, col = mouse, label = diff)) +
        geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = min, xmax = max)) +
        geom_text_repel() +
        theme_minimal() +
        theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
              legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! would you mind explaining the step where you use `mutate()` with `ifelse()` to create `min` and `max`? I don't completely understand this, and it seems essential for this solution to work.

Comment: @Emman sure! :) `geom_pointrange` requires `min` and `max`  of each `line` to be plotted. I used `ifelse` to create new variables that contain `max` and `min` values of the lines to be plotted.  These new variables control where your `lines` start and end.  You can also manually give your `xmin` and `xmax` points for each `line`  as a `vector` (of 4 in this case)

Answer (score 1):

To give an overview which tools you can use and hw they work, have a look at this code

```
#Draw horizontal lines and set up plot
maxAbsDiff <- max(abs(df_with_diff$diff))
xLimits <- c(-2*maxAbsDiff,2*maxAbsDiff)
p <- ggplot() + geom_hline(yintercept = 1:NROW(df_with_diff)) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x=0,y=1:NROW(df_with_diff))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = xLimits, expand=c(0,0)) + labs(x=NULL,y=NULL,title = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:NROW(df_with_diff), labels = df_with_diff$mouse)

#Draw the lines decoding the diff
lineData <- data.frame(xStart=rep(0,NROW(df_with_diff)), xEnd = df_with_diff$diff, 
                       yStart = 1:NROW(df_with_diff)+0.2, yEnd =1:NROW(df_with_diff)+0.2, 
                       col = paste0("something_",1:NROW(df_with_diff)))

p <- p + geom_segment(data = lineData, mapping = aes(x=xStart,xend = xEnd, y = yStart, yend = yEnd, col = col))
p <- p + theme(legend.position = "none")

#Anotate with the diff-values
annotationData <- data.frame(xpos = df_with_diff$diff/2, ypos = 1:NROW(df_with_diff)+0.5, lab = as.character(df_with_diff$diff))
p <- p + annotate(geom = "text", x = annotationData$xpos, y = annotationData$ypos, label = annotationData$lab)
```

producing
[image]

Its not styled like you want, but looking at the documentation of the used functions, you should easily get what you want. To get rid og the backgounr,d have a look at the documentation of the `theme`-function. I think ggplot also offers something like an empty theme or void theme, such that you have a shortcut for removing the grids instead of setting all the parameters of `theme`.